# Destacar botão página atual com base em outra página

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo o menu baixo, que está contido na página `empresas.php` e ao "Editar" uma empresa passa a ser `editar-empresa.php?id=x`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função que adiciona a classe `active` à página atual é a seguinte:

```
(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('menu'),
        anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        current = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
            if(anchor[i].href.split("?")[0] == current) {
                anchor[i].children[0].className = "active";
            }
    }
})();
```

Ou seja, a seção "Empresas" só permanecerá destacada se estiver na página `empresas.php`, porém necessito que permaneça destacada ao ir para o subseção `editar-empresa.php?id=x`. O que devo fazer para que tal objetivo seja alcançado?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="emissor-nfe.php"><li>Emissor NF-e</li></a>
            <a href="empresas.php"><li>Empresas</li></a>
            <a href="clientes.php"><li>Clientes</li></a>
            <a href="produtos.php"><li>Produtos</li></a>
            <a href="transportadoras.php"><li>Transportadoras</li></a>
            <a href="logout.php"><li>Sair</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Se você puder mudar o nome do arquivo para `editar-empresas.php`, poderia fazer algo como `if (current.indexOf(anchor) >= 0)`. Assim, seria procurado o texto `empresas.php` em `editar-empresas.php` e, se achar, define como ativo, mas não sei se é uma solução muito boa.

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, poderia detalhar mais sua solução?

Comment: Assim que eu conseguir um tempo livre eu vejo se faço uma resposta.

Comment: Lembrando que utilizar elementos `a` dentro de um `ul` é sintática e semanticamente errado. Se o seu objetivo é fazer com que todo o `li` responda ao evento do link, veja esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221187/5878

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o conselho do @AndersonCarlosWoss, uma possível solução é renomear o nome da página `editar-empresas.php` para `empresas-editar.php` e utilizar a função `indexOf()`:

```
(function () {
    var nav = document.getElementById('menu'),
        anchor = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        current = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        if (current.indexOf(anchor[i].toString().split(".")[0]) >= 0) {
            anchor[i].children[0].className = "active";
        }
    }
})();
```

Obs.: a função `split()` foi utilizada para desconsiderar a extensão `.php` (lembrando que ela só trabalha com *strings* e por isso foi utilizado o método `toString()`).

Comment: E funcionou assim?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim.