# Clicando na <li> o link <a> também funcionar

Tags: html, css

Sempre tenho essa dúvida, olhem só:

Tenho um menu, com ul e li:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Como faço, pra que, quando eu posicionar ou clicar na `li`  o link do `a` funcionar? Porque, por exemplo, só funciona se eu clicar no `a`, mas, se eu clicar fora, no caso, na `li`, não funciona, o link `a` não ativa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você definir no CSS

```
li a {
   display: block;
}
```

A tag "A" passa a ter a mesma largura do "LI", consequentemente tudo fica com link.

Comment: Isso é um comportamento dependente de navegador, não? Fora o fato de mudar comportamento de aplicação através de seu estilo.

Comment: @Renan isso deve funcionar em qualquer navegador, basicamente o display:block força o link a se comportar como uma div, que por padrão ocupa 100% da área disponível, sendo assim o mesmo tamanho para o link e para o item da lista.

Comment: Eu vejo problemas na abordagem sugerida pelo @LINQ que inverte as tags. Mesmo sabendo que funciona, e que no HTML5 essas regras de DOM são mais liberais, não me parece o caminho ideal...

Comment: Eu concordo que a resposta do @LINQ não é a ideal e já deixei comentário nela. Mas volto a dizer que esta resposta acopla a lógica ao estilo, o que é bizarro. Você muda o comportamento do seu código e pode gerar um bug apenas mudando o CSS.

Comment: Dica fantástica, ajudou demais, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Tenta algo como:

```js
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Esta resposta deveria ser marcada como a correta.

Comment: Poderia explicar, Renan, a resposta do Evandro? Em diversos locais que procurei, me indicaram a fazer do modo dele. Porque se não, todo menu que eu for criar, eu terei que fazer um script.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho a resposta do Mathias só precisa ser aplicada uma vez para todo o site, portanto não requer repetição. A resposta do Evandro não me parece a ideal porque acopla o comportamento da aplicação ao estilo dela. Você poderá introduzir um bug no seu sistema apenas mudando o CSS.

Comment: Por exemplo, aqui no SOpt, no menu, a tag a está como inline-block, isso não é ideal no caso?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho inline-block permite que você defina uma largura para tag "a" e ao mesmo tempo coloque um item ao lado do outro, a solução do SOpt está correta também, e ao meu ver nada disso altera o comportamento da aplicação como o Renan afirma, isso só muda o estilo, e se você rodar o site sem CSS os links vão funcionar normalmente, e o código será validado como correto em qualquer validador de HTML. Esse debate aqui prova que há várias maneiras para resolver o mesmo problema, algumas simples, outras mais complexas e alguma não recomendadas. Mas talvez só Sr. Tim Bernes Lee saiba a correta

Answer (score 2):

Eu acredito que utilizar JavaScript (e principalmente jQuery) para alterar o comportamento natural do elemento `li` também não é a melhor solução. Esse é um caso clássico de delegar uma função para um elemento que não é o mais indicado.

[Qual é o impacto de se alterar o comportamento padrão de um elemento HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212270/5878)

Se o evento em questão redirecionará o usuário para outra página, este evento deve estar delegado ao elemento `a` e não ao elemento `li`. Implementar o segundo é quebrar a semântica do HTML. Agora, se a intenção é que o comportamento do elemento `a` seja aplicado em todo o elemento `li`, a solução mais clara é: fazer com que o elemento `a` ocupe todo o elemento `li`.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

li > a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Não fere a semântica do HTML e não utiliza JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

A melhor forma é a junção de duas alternativas acima.

Coloque a âncora com height e widht de 100%, e display block.

Irá funcionar e não alterará a semântica do HTML.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).